# Can't Acess the CP - Unable to load class jquery

Tags: control-panel

Went to log into a local dev site tonight and suddenly get this error:

```
An Error was encountered
Unable to load the requested class: jquery
```

I have no idea what might have changed.  I've replaced all of the files in the system folder, and have slowly gone back through the themes folder, replacing everything I could think of, and making sure that all of the add-ons were updated.

Currently running EE 2.6.1 with the master config in place.  I enabled debug = 1 in the admin.php file but it doesn't show anything else.  The front end of the site comes up as expected.

Anyone happen to see this before?

Todd

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it might be an issue with the native jQuery module. Those files are in /system/expressionengine/modules/. Replace those to be sure something didn't get accidently deleted.

Comment: I wasn't sure exactly where those files were, but I replaced everything in the system folder (and copied back my config and database files).  I replaced the entire /themes folder, copying back my third party themes and CP themes. So I figured it could only be my 3rd party add-ons (which is why I was going back through and making sure they were all there) or something with the DB. Strange.

Comment: So still broken? or fixed?

Comment: After spending too much time with this, I ended up rebuilding from scratch....  :(  So this can be closed.